# Javascript sendBeacon sending duplicate GET and POST at same time

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

Why does navigator.sendBeacon() submit a GET and a POST request. On top of this it's not all the time it usually sends just POST request but every so often it sends a GET request before the POST and the timestamps are identical in the network tab using browser dev tools.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('time_log_id', time_log_id);
navigator.sendBeacon(BASE_URL + "Course/ajaxTimeUpdate/beacon", fd);
```

It's causing a problem in that my backend framework will ignore (for setting a "previous/back url" ajax requests looking for $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = xmlhttprequest which it does ignore when the POST goes through but when the GET request goes through it does not ignore it I am guessing xmlhttprequest isn't found. Regardless of that it shouldn't be sending a GET request anyway. Also in the browser dev toolbar the POST request has a stacktrace and the GET request does not include one (using Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0).

Only other difference I could see is the "initiator" column says "document" on the GET request and "myfile.js:19 (beacon)" on the POST. There is only 1 function that sends the request and it's only called once on unload.

Any help into figuring out what's going on and stopped the GET request would be greatly appreciated.